# Monitoring the data usage of each device attached to the android hotspot

Tags: android, linux-kernel, wifi, android-wifi, android-kernel

Fellow Craftsmen.....
I'm trying to create an application that can monitor the data usage of each device that is attached to the Android mobile hotspot. From what I have seen the TrafficStats class can only return usage per UID (application) however I want to see the usage per attached Wi-Fi device. Has anyone figured this out yet or have any ideas that I can try? Perhaps I need to be talking directly to the kernel?

Comment: Do you have your application on all the devices i.e. one creating the hotspot and the other ones connecting to it ?

Comment: nope - just an application on the one creating the hotspot

Comment: I don't think this doable with current APIs unless you have your app on all the devices.